# Sometimes unable to update the kafka offset from producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We could able to insert data to kafka using kafka producer API and offset got incremented as well could able to consume data using kafka consumer API and consumer offset got incremented.

But sometimes,  Offset was not working properly in the process of push and consume data from kafka. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you provide a full example of how you are checking these values?

Comment: Here is the command to know offset value. bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server hostname:9092 --describe --group production-consumer-group